# Trying to generate key hash for Android Facebook with keytool

Tags: android, facebook

So I am trying to get a hash so Facebook can use SSO with my android app, but I am having an issue.

so I run this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias statusp -keystore my-release-key.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

And it gives me an error that `-exportcert` is an illegal option, but it still gives me a key hash! However, it gives me the same key hash if I use the debug key template Facebook provides. So I don't think it's right. It also didn't ask me for my password(s) when making the key hash.

This seems so simple, yet I don't know why I'm having so much trouble. Can anyone offer any hints or suggestions?

Comment: okay so I solved this out myself so I figured I would post my solution: don't use the one that comes with eclipse. It's outdated, and the same commands don't work on it. find keytool in your java installation.

Comment: I use a Mac and im getting the same error when i use the Terminal with the above line. How can I use the keytool in the java installation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I spend a couple of hours to find a solution, but actually the Facebook SDK provides the solution by itself.

in the DialogListener class I modified the onFacebookError method:

```
 @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
         Log.d("myTag",error.getmessage);
    }
```

Execute the app (which was sign with the same key i use for the market), and on LogCat will be a message under this tag with the correct key.

We had also created a simple project which does all the work, and returns the correct key on an alert-box and on LogCat. You can find it on [our blog](http://www.quintostdio.com/blog/archives/957).